# Left and right eigenvectors of transfer matrix in matrix product states (MPS)

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, tensor-network

Let

$$\lvert{\psi}\rangle=\sum_{i_1i_2...i_n}Tr(A^{[1]}_{i_1}A^{[2]}_{i_2}...A^{[n]}_{i_n})\lvert{i_1 i_2...i_n}\rangle$$

be a MPS, where $i_k=1,2...d$ and $A^{[k]}_{i_k}$ are $D\times D$ matrices on site $k$. We know we can construct the "Transfer Matrix" $E^{[k]}$ as:

$$E^{[k]}=\sum_{i_k} A_{i_k}^{[k]}\otimes {A_{i_k}^{*}}^{[k]}.$$

We also have the freedom to choose the $A^{[k]}_{i_k}$ matrices such that [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0608197):

$$\sum_{i_k} A_{i_k}^{[k]}{A_{i_k}^{\dagger}}^{[k]}=I \tag1$$

$$\sum_{i_k} {A^\dagger}_{i_k}^{[k]}\Lambda^{[k-1]}{A_{i_k}}^{[k]}=\Lambda^{[k]} \tag2$$

where $\Lambda^{[k]}$ is a diagonal matrix with $Tr(\Lambda^{[k]})=1$ containing the eigenvalues of the reduced density matrix $\rho_k=Tr_{k+1,...n}\lvert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\rvert$.

We can think of $E^{[k]}$ as a $D^2\times D^2$ matrix and I need to find the right and left eigenvectors of $E^{[k]}$ corresponding to the eigenvalue 1.

Using $(1)$ it is easy to see that $I$ is a right eigenvector:

$$E^{[k]}(I)=I$$

but from $(2)$:

$${E^{*}}^{[k]}(\Lambda^{[k-1]})=\Lambda^{[k]}\neq\Lambda^{[k-1]}$$

so $\Lambda^{[k-1]}$ should not be a left eigenvector from my understanding but in the literature it is treated as such and $E^{[k]}$ is expressed as:

$$E^{[k]}=\lvert I \rangle\langle\Lambda^{[k-1]}\rvert +  \cdots$$

Where am I wrong?

**Reference**

**[1]** D. Perez-Garcia, F. Verstraete, M.M. Wolf and J.I. Cirac, "Matrix product state representations", *Quantum Inf. Comput.* **7**, 401 (2007), [arXiv:quant-ph/0608197 (page 6)](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0608197).

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to find the eigenvector.  Are you assuming translational invariance? Can you give a reference for the last formula you give?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I'm not assuming translational invariance. I want to find the right and left eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue 1 (assumed to be non-degenerate) because under RG transformation the tensor $E$ flows to the fixed point $E^{\infty}=\lim_{ n\to\infty} E^{n}$ which is given by the tensor product of these two eigenvectors.
Here https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0410227, at page 3 , $E^{\infty}=\lvert\phi_{R}\rangle\langle\phi_{L}\rvert$ where $\lvert\phi_{R}\rangle=I$ and $\lvert\phi_{L}\rangle=\Lambda$.

Comment: RG doesn't make much sense without a notion of translational invariance. Note that e.g. Eq. (3) in said paper is tinv.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Yes, you're right, I considered the wrong example. Here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.3745.pdf at page 5 they consider a non translation invariant mps, but they're using a slight different expression for $A_{i_k}^{[k]}$, and so the eingenvectors are $\delta^{[k]}_{\alpha\gamma}\lambda^{[k]}_{\alpha}$ and $\delta^{[k+1]}_{\beta\chi}\lambda^{[k+1]}_{\beta}$ where here ${(\lambda^{[k]}_{\alpha})}^2$ are the eigenvalues of $\Lambda^{[k]}$.

Comment: All right. And where are they talking about the eigenvectors of the non-tinv E?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Paragraph IV, page 5

Comment: That looks odd. I'd say there is some tacit assumption, such as tinv (and the label is only there to highlight which sites one is talking about). But you can try pinging Xiao-Gang Wen, he's posting here occasionally.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Non-translational invariance is actually explicitly assumed. From the article : "Consider a generic system without any symmetry (including
translation symmetry) ... ".
Do you mean I can tag him with @?

Comment: You can tag him with @ if you comment under one of his posts or in a thread where he commented.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion arises because the notation hints at an inner product, which is nowhere defined. I will maybe make things a bit more complicated than is needed in practice, but i hope it helps.

Denote by $M^{[k]}$ the space of $D_k\times D_k$-matrices, and let $1_k$ be the unit matrix of $M^{[k]}$. Then the transfer operator is a map

$$ E^{[k]} : M^{[k]} \rightarrow M^{[k+1]}  \ . $$

One demands that

$$ E^{[k]}(1_k) = 1_{k+1} $$

The above enables us to write

$$ E^{[k]} = 1_{k+1} \otimes \lambda_k  + \cdots $$

where $\lambda_k \in (M^{[k]})^*$ is the linear functional dual to $1_k$. In order to go to Dirac bra-ket notation, we have to identify $M^{[k]}$ with its dual space. The most straightforward way to do this is probably to equip $M^{[k]}$ with the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product $(X,Y) \mapsto \langle X , Y \rangle = \text{tr}(X^*Y)$ and then define the anti-linear  Riesz isomorphism $R(X) = \langle X, \cdot\rangle$. Then a matrix $X$ is represented by the ket $| X \rangle$, and one may write $R(X) = \langle X |$.

We may thus write

$$E^{[k]} = |1_{k+1}\rangle \langle \Lambda_k |  + \cdots $$

If one sets $D_k = D$ a constant, then, of course, one may identify all the $M^{[k]}$ and the $1_k$'s.